# Dispose em Unit Of Work

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, using

Tenho uma *web application* e estou utilizando repositório* e *Unit Of Work*.

Em alguns exemplos vi que após realizar alguma operação de alteração no banco devemos chamar o método `Dispose()`.

Instancei o `UnitOfWork`:

```
    private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
```

Ao realizar um alteração de *update* e chamar o `Dispose()`, não é possível fazer o *bind* no *grid*, pois, o objeto passou pelo `Dispose()`.

Como alternativa, estou usando o `using`:

```
    using (UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        //Código.
    }
```

Minha dúvida é: utilizando o *pattern* **Unit Of Work** é correto usar o `using`? Se não, onde devo chamar o `Dispose()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende da implementação desta classe [`UnitOfWork`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Sei que tem umas que realmente usam o [`Dispose()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Essa parece ser o caso, então é para usar sempre que o objeto deva ser liberado.

Pelo que está escrito na pergunta não é o que deseja, você quer que ele continue vivo, então porque está usando o `using`? Esse recurso é para garantir que o objeto morra no final do escopo. Só use um recurso quando é o que deseja.

Então o problema não tem a ver com o `UnitOfWork` e sim com o que deseja fazer.

Claro que precisará liberar o objeto em algum momento. Terá que ver onde é o local adequado de fazer essa liberação. Não temos como saber, só você conhece o seu código e sua necessidade.

Gerenciamento de memória não é tão simples quanto parece.

Pelos comentários a aplicação é web, portanto deve executar de forma efêmera, então ao final da execução da rotina toda a memória será liberada, então não é necessário usar o `using`.

Comment: ♦, 
o meu questinamento é exatamente sobre onde fazer o Dispose(). Uma vez que em _Web Application_ não estou usando _controllers_. O uso do  using() é apenas para  liberar recurso, porém, para isso tenho que fazer várias instâncias  do **Unit Of Work** e a ideia é não ter que instânciar a classe várias vezes.

Comment: Não temos como saber ao certo, você só postou um trecho. Porém para web há uma chance de sequer precisar do `using`. Se rodar por um tempo muito curto, fazer uma ou mais tarefas específicas e encerrar, o que é muito comum em web, ele não é necessário. Aplicações efêmeras não precisam de tantos cuidados.

Comment: entendo.
Estou usando um _RadGrid_ do **Telerik** para fazer o **CRUD**, diretamente no grid. Então, basicamente, tenho um _NeedDataSource_, para carregar os dados e utilizo os **Command** para _Insert_, _Update_ e _Delete_.

Comment: Quem deu o negativo poderia dizer o que tem de errado para eu corrigir. Estou seguro que não tem nada errado, mas a pessoa pode ajudar todo mundo.